# How can I position a jQuery modal box?

Tags: jquery

Can I place a jQuery modal box in a specific location on the page? For example, showing it in the top right or bottom left.

Can I specify pixels or screen location for where this modal box should show?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yup. Just look at the id of the containing div, set the position to absolute, then put your coordinates like so:

```
top left => top: 0; left: 0
```

or

```
bottom left => bottom: 0; left: 0
```

Comment: thanks ,its working.
i was thinking like javascript popup we can put position.
anyway jquery is full of styles.